# COM/OLE, Old code and Headaches

Tags: com, ole, legacy

I'm currently living in 90's and I've been handed this piece of legacy code. I'm not knowledgeable when it comes to COM/OLE/MFC/ATL so I'm asking this, hoping that someone with experience from way back then, could help me to track down this issue.

- What I have is this really old/legacy MFC/ATL application.
- It launches, but eventually crashes in CFormView::HandleInitDialog (atlmfc\src\mfc\viewform.cpp)

The debug output I get is this:

```
CoCreateInstance of OLE control {6A24B340-7634-11D3-A5B0-0050044A7E1A} failed.
>>> Result code: 0x80040154
>>> Is the control is properly registered?
```

I know as much that this is due to some component registration failure, or resolution but what I do not know is how to figure out what this dependency is, I have a working old executable of the code, and maybe I could use a bit of reverse engineering to figure out if any DLLs are missing, but I really don't know, I have know idea what OLE is, and I would really appreciate some help on how to debug this.

Comment: To help anyone who gets a similar problem, I had a crash like this and I clicked the `ocx` which was getting unloaded, and dependency walker opened up. It showed that the `ocx` wasn't able to open a certain dll, which when I placed in the correct path, the program ran without crashing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that looks like it is dxDBGrid.dll.  OLE is just Object Linking and Embedding.  You need to find the dxDBGrid.dll and make sure it is registered.  you can use regsvr32 to register it.

[explanation of regsvr32](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490985.aspx)

Comment: Might be blocked by his virus scanner too.

Comment: you could search the registry ... if the file is being loaded from a file path that is hard coded the file might not be where you expect it... (ie program files vs program files (x86))

Comment: That could very much be the case, but do you know it's the dxDBGrid and not some other component, among all the DLLs I got, I'd like to know which contain what. Like I said, it's legacy code, I don't fully understand everything yet... isn't their someway to figure out what GUIDs are contained in a specific DLL?

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=7007  is a link to oleview which should let you peak inside it.

Comment: Also the GUID associated with the com component is suppose to be unique.  So I searched for the guid in google to find what component has that clsid and that is what turned up.  So I am reasonably sure.

Comment: The OLE Viewer is really old and it has some components missing as well, but it seems to work, the tool is a bit strange but I guess this was the kind of answer is was looking for.